# Fastest way to traverse columns in a multidimensional array in C

Tags: c, optimization, multidimensional-array, pointer-arithmetic

I'm currently working on a program to solve the red/blue computation; program is written in C.

Description of the problem is here : http://www.cs.utah.edu/~mhall/cs4961f10/CS4961-L9.pdf

tl;dr you have a grid of colors (red/blue/white), first red cells move to the right according to certain rules, then blue cells move down according to other rules.

I've got my program working and giving correct output, and I'm now trying to see if I can't speed it up at all.

Using Intel's VTune Amplifier (this is for a parallel programming course, and we're doing pthreads in visual studio with parallel studio integrated), I've identified that the biggest hotspot in my code is when moving blue cells.

Implementation details: grid is stored as a dynamically allocated int **, set up this way

```
globalBoard = malloc(sizeof(int *) * size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        globalBoard[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
            globalBoard[i][j] = rand() % 3;
    }
```

After some research, I believe the cause of the hotspot (almost 4 times as much CPU time as moving red cells) is cache misses when traversing column by column.

I understand that under the hood, this grid will be stored as a 1d array, so when I move red cells to the right and go row by row, I'm most often checking contiguous values, so the CPU doesn't need to load new values into the cache as often, whereas going column by column results in jumping around through the array by amounts that only increase as the size of the board does.

All that being said, I want this particular section to go faster. Here's the code as it stands now :

```
void blueStep(int col)
{
    int i;
    int local[size];
    for (i = 0; i < size; local[i] = globalBoard[i++][col]);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (i < size - 1)
        {
            if (globalBoard[i][col] == 2 && globalBoard[i + 1][col] == 0)
            {
                local[i++] = 0;
                local[i] = 2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (globalBoard[i][col] == 2 && globalBoard[0][col] == 0)
            {
                local[i++] = 0;
                local[0] = 2;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        globalBoard[i][col] = local[i];

}
```

Here, col is which column to work on and size is how big the grid is (it's always square).

I was thinking that I might be able to do some kind of fancy pointer arithmetic to speed this up, and was reading this : http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html.

Looking at that, I feel like I might need to change how I declare the grid in order to take advantage of 2d array pointer arithmetic, but I'm still not sure how I would go about traversing columns using that method.

Any help with that, or any other suggestions of fast ways to go through a column are welcome.

UPDATE: After a bit more research and discussion, it would seem my assumptions were incorrect. Turns out it's actually taking almost twice as long to write the results back to the global array than it is to loop over columns, due to false sharing. That said, I'm still somewhat curious to see if there are any better ways of doing column traversal.

Comment: Why don't you allocate the array in a single contiguous block?

Comment: I suggested an answer to a similar question there:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480911/2d-array-vs-structure-of-an-array

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is to process the grid in tiles.  You can do a very quick tile move, either down or right, in a 16x16 or 32x32 tile.  They two moves will be effectively the same, and run at the same speed: read all values into XMM registers, process, write.  You may want to investigate MASKMOVDQU instruction here.  If I understand the nature of the problem, you can overlap tiles by one row/column and this will work okay if you process them in the usual (scan) order.  If not, you have to handle stitching the tiles separately.

There is no *truly* fast way to do this in C code.  However, you can try (1) changing your board type to be a unit8_t, (2) replacing all if .. statements with arithmetic, like this: value = (mask & value) | (^mask & newvalue), and (3) turning on maximum loop unrolling and auto-vectorization in the compiler options.  This will give you a nice speedup - especially avoiding conditionals.

*EDIT* In addition to tiles that can fit in registers, you can also do a second level of tiles sized to fit in your cache.  I think the combination will run at roughly your memory bandwidth.

*EDIT* Or, make your board type be two bits: pack four cells to a byte.  Goes nicely with the replacing if statements with arithmetic idea :)